# How can I assign the output of a function to a variable in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, variables

I have the following HTML code:

```
<section>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</section>
```

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$("div").on("mouseenter", function (){
    myidx = $(this).index();
    return myidx;
});

var x = something // The value myidx;
```

I want to assign the output of the function executed on `mouseenter` which is the value of `myidx` to var `x`. So that: var `x` = the value of `myidx`.

Comment: Please don't radically change questions after answers have been posted. If you have a new or different question, simply post another question (and link the two if they are related to the same problem).

Comment: You have changed the scope of the question (see the edit review). Be clear what you want, and don't change it. You're asking first A , then B after your edit.

Comment: @Joelmm I've rolled this question back to the version before it was changed, so the answers are still valid, and [posted a question on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289791/rolling-back-radical-edits-by-the-op-after-answers-were-posted) asking how best to handle this. If you feel the edits were appropriate, by all means roll forward again, but please make sure you post different question separately.

Comment: This question is being [discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289791/1159478).

Comment: Your edit was very helpful, but I suspect your question still isn't quite clear enough to get a good answer. When and how do you want to read `x`? Surely you don't expect `x` to have a value as soon as the page loads, before the user has moved the mouse. So when *do* you need `x` to have a value? What are you using `x` for? How and when do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = newFunction();
```

should do it.

Comment: Please review the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function newFunction (){
  // calculate the value of var newVar;

  return newVar;
}

var x = newFunction(); // Get's value of newVar;
```

Comment: How is this different from the first answer and all the comments?

Comment: Please review the question. Thanks

Comment: @Joelmm You changed a question from one to another?! You are suppose to ask a NEW question for that, not edit an old one.